# Why are fringes formed in the Michelson-Morely interferometer?

Tags: special-relativity

[image]
(Assuming the hypothesis of the experiment is null)

Why are there fringes at the observer? From what I can understand of the experiment, the only reason why this can happen is if the light at the source is not coherent(however non-coherent light would make this experiment useless) or because of experimental inaccuracies(the distances of the mirrors cannot be exactly the same, and this could be significant with visible light having a short wavelength). The reason why I think they should be in phase is because both rays have theoretically traveled exactly the same path distance, so there is no reason why after the final reflection towards the observer, the waves are not in phase.

A video that I watched that I hoped would explain this is found here https://youtu.be/JO8TMNJLit8 (skip to 2:40). However, I do not buy this explanation. If both rays, after reflecting off the mirrors, meet at the intersection shown in the picture at the start of the post, then from then on would have the same path distance from the intersection to any point on the telescope, so would have no reason not to arrive in phase. However, I could see that as an experimental imperfection, that the light rays will not form a perfect intersection and be on the order of nanometers off, causing the interference patterns.

Comment: Are you considering only one ray that splits into two, then is recombined into one?  That is not sufficient to produce fringes.  You need multiple rays.

Comment: Have you looked into any textbooks on this?

Comment: @S.McGrew See https://imgur.com/a/Ka3um8X , where waves 1,2,3 would necessarily be in phase, and the difference is colour is just for clarity on the diagram. Is this what you are suggesting? That rays arrive at slightly different positions on the silvered block due to the width of the beam, and this causes the fringes.

Comment: @my2cts This question is overlooked/assumed obvious in everything I have read

Comment: The ray diagram in yoir link is not correct.  There is no physical basis for the rays to diverge upon reflection from the beamsplitter on one side. I will compose an answer rhat is more complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a good one.  It is based on your intuition that for parallel rays, flat beamsplitter, flat mirror, and perfect alignment; the split rays will travel exactly the same distances.  Your intuition is right.

In a Michaelson interferometer with that description, you *don't* see fringes: instead you see either a uniform light field or a uniform dark field, or something in between, depending on the relative distance between the beamsplitters and the two mirrors.

In order to see fringes, a little bit of misalignment is necessary.  Usually one of the mirrors is very slightly tilted, or the beamsplitter is tilted slightly away from 45 degrees. With that tilt, linear fringes appear.  As the tilt is reduced, the fringes get wider and wider apart.  As the tilt goes to zero, the fringes become infinitely wide and you see a uniform light field instead of fringes.

If the incoming beam is not collimated and instead is diverging or converging, circular fringes will appear. Add tilt, and the center of the circular fringes will move sideways.

Comment: It is helpful to think of what the observer sees in the 'slightly misaligned case'. They see  two images of the 'monochromatic light source', which is presumably a slit. One image is a reflection in M2 of the source as reflected in the half silvered block. The second is the reflection in the block of the source as reflected in M1.  The misalignment means the images don't quite lie on top of each other, so this is basically the same as Young's 2 slits.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on this subject. However, I'm sure that we are not allowed to use simple geometrical optic. Instead, we have to use **Rayleigh-Sommerfeld's diffraction formula** to obtain the image at the detector. This formula reads,
\begin{align}
U(x_i,y_i,z_i) &\propto \int dx_s \int dy_s \; U_s(x_s, y_s) \;
e^{-i \frac{k}{2z_i}((x_i-x_s)^2 + (y_i-y_s)^2)}
\\
&= e^{-i \frac{k}{2z_i}(x_i^2 + y_i^2)}
\int dx_s \int dy_s \; U_s(x_s, y_s)  \;
e^{-i \frac{k}{2z_i}(x_s^2 + y_s^2)}
e^{+i \frac{k}{z_i}(x_sx_i + y_sx_i)}
\\
&= e^{-i \frac{k}{2z_i}(x_i^2 + y_i^2)} \;
\mathbb{F}\{U_s(x_s, y_s) \;
e^{-i \frac{k}{2z}(x_s^2 + y_s^2)}\}(\frac{x_i}{\lambda z_i},
\frac{y_i}{\lambda z_i})
\end{align}
where the index $s$ is used for the source coordinates (=inputs), the index $i$ for the image coordinates, and $\mathbb{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform. Looking at the  so called *chirp* function in front of the Fourier transform, we would  naturally assume to find a fringe pattern at the detector, and not homogeneous field.

This argument is extremely simplified, because we just omitted the Fourier transform. Calculating this Fourier transform is not just a minor detail, but the main subject of Fourier optics. Hence, one should not expect that the simple quadratic phase relation holds in general. Nevertheless,  the simple argument presented above tells us that we should not expect a single fringe, but a fringe pattern. This is exactly, what we observe in the Michelson experiment.

Comment: Im sure this is very true, but is there not a simple qualitative answer?

Comment: So, does this mean that if the light from source is collimated, there is no tilt in the mirrors and beam splitter is exactly 45 degrees, then also fringes would be observed? (Opposite to what is being implied in the answer by S. McGrew)